# Calculate Time To Failure TTF in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to write function in SQL server to find the Previous `TTF` (time to failure) in this table for each time records

```
 time       machine_id  event_type  Previous TTF 
0           97957590    0
64082917976 97957590    1
64508629318 97957590    0
94842321864 97957590    1
95269562076 97957590    0
2.33418E+12 97957590    1
2.33458E+12 97957590    0
```

Other machine has `event_type=2` means updates, but this have to do nothing with calculation

```
time      machine_id    event_type
0           3585557842  0
2.22403E+12 3585557842  1
2.22487E+12 3585557842  0
2.22488E+12 3585557842  2
2.23928E+12 3585557842  2
2.25875E+12 3585557842  1
2.26948E+12 3585557842  0
2.26948E+12 3585557842  2
2.49999E+12 3585557842  2
```

Where, `event_type = 0` is when machine added, and `event_type= 1` is when machine failed
Technically, `TTF  (time-to-failure)` is the time period from
an Add event to a failure event (`time` in `event = 1` is subtracted from `time` in `event = 0`)

Expected result is like this table:

```
time        machine_id  event_type  Previous TTF
0           97957590    0           0
64082917976 97957590    1           0
64508629318 97957590    0           64082917976
94842321864 97957590    1           64082917976
95269562076 97957590    0           30333692546
2.33418E+12 97957590    1           30333692546
2.33458E+12 97957590    0           2.23891E+12
```

My function is

```
alter function FnGetTTF(@mach_id bigint, @actualTime bigint)
RETURNS float
AS
BEGIN

declare @TTF float
declare @timelastfailurehappen float
declare @timelastaddhappen  float

select top 1 @timelastfailurehappen= [time] 
from machine_events 
where machine_id = @mach_id and event_type =1 and [time] <= @actualTime 
order by [time] desc

select top 1 @timelastaddhappen =[time] 
from machine_events 
where machine_id = @mach_id and event_type =0 and [time] <= @actualTime 
order by [time] desc

if( @timelastfailurehappen > @timelastaddhappen)
set @TTF = @timelastfailurehappen - @timelastaddhappen 

return @TTF
END
```

My current issues, my function only calculate `TTF` a for records that `event_type =1` and `null` value for other records

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with window functions.  Assuming the 0s and 1s are intermixed:

```
select me.time, me.machine_id, me.event_type,
       (case when event_type = 1
             then lag(ttf, 2, 0) over (partition by machine_id order by time)
             else lag(ttf, 1, 0) over (partition by machine_id order by time)
        end) as prev_ttf
from (select me.*,
             (case when event_type = 1
                   then time - lag(time) over (partition by machine_id order by time)
              end) as ttf
      from machine_events me
     ) me;
```

If your 0s and 1s are not interleaved, I would suggest that you ask another question, with a more appropriate set of sample data.

Comment: @jou . . . I would suggest you ask *another* question.  The answer is rather different for that situation, and your sample data clearly suggests that the data is interleaved (changing your question now would invalidate this answer, which can draw downvotes).

Comment: Thnx, @GordonLinoff, your script worked for this sample data. However, I prefer to create a function, so for example at any time period that I need TTF for this machine, function should generate valid data. As you can see my function has parameter actual time, means any time I need. I dont get clear idea of intermixed value. I believe lag function might not work well.

Comment: @jou . . . The window functions are likely to be much, much, much better in terms of performance, compared to a single row approach.

Comment: Yeap I test it no need to join tables. However, in the query you post I still need to adjust it for purpose 1) passing machine_id, time parameters to get TTF value.  2) adjust your query to be working event_type=2